# rancher network docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rancher

compose this .yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    expose:
      - 80
    restart: always
    networks:
      - nginx-proxy
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=blog.gerling.one
    container_name: wordpress

networks:
  nginx-proxy:
    external: true
```

when i run the docker-compose.yml with

```
docker-compose up
```

the container starts with Network: nginx-proxy  -> `all Works`

but when i start with

```
rancher-compose <API SETTINGS> up
```

the container starts with Network: Managed and nothing works

Yeah its right that nothing works but how i can start with nginx-proxy in rancheros?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Comment: No, the Problem still exist. But i have a little workaround. I make a network_mode: bridge and use the default bridge.

Comment: What problem are you still facing?

Comment: I want to use network_mode: bridge with a custom bridge not the default. And This all with rancher-compose

Comment: First thing, docker networks are not supported in Rancher. Although you can use a different bridge other than `docker0` at the time of environment creations by customizing the IPSec template.

Answer (score 0):

Networking in Rancher is different from Docker. So the docker compose file doesn't work as-is. To achieve what you are trying to accomplish there are a few options:

- Checkout the Wordpress Catalog item in Rancher Catalog
- Manually start Wordpress service and create a Load Balancer in Rancher UI and use the Host information there.